# 'invalid literal for int() with base 10:' error when retrieving record with Django REST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Basically I am trying to retrieve information on a specific VIN for car, I do so with the URL pattern: `ValueError at /api/v1/purchases/1D7RV1CT0AS168723/` with the VIN there as the pk. It was working fine before, not sure what changed

views.py

```
 -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, get_list_or_404
from .models import GetPurchases, CarFax
from .serializers import PurchasesSerializer
from .serializers import CarFaxSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response

# Create your views here.

class getPurchases(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ''' The actions provided by the ModelViewSet class are .list(), .retrieve(),
      .create(), .update(), .partial_update(), and .destroy(). '''

    queryset = GetPurchases.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PurchasesSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        # accessed at url: ^api/v1/purchases/$
        queryset = GetPurchases.objects.all()
        serializer = PurchasesSerializer(queryset, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        # accessed at url: ^api/v1/purchases/{pk}/$

        queryset = GetPurchases.objects.all()
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404
        record = get_object_or_404(queryset, vin__exact=pk)
        serializer = PurchasesSerializer(record)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: It looks like the primary key is an integer, but you entered a non-numerical string.

Comment: does it have to be an integer? I think I did change something, I changed the code to use `vin__exact=pk` which im pretty what it was before.

Comment: it does not have to be an `int`eger, but something that can be converted to an `int`, for example `'foob4r'` can *not* be converted to an `int`, furthermore you can of course make the primary key of your `GetPurchaes` a *non-int*, but then we would not get this error here.

Comment: Does my edit not do that essentially? In my edit I'm looking up by the 'vin' field and not the primary key

Comment: I fixed the issue, I'm an idiot I was in the wrong project folder and therefore editing the wrong code, thanks guys